# No class definitiion found / failed resolution of android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

When executing:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
  .addApi(LocationServices.API)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
  .build();
```

I have included android-support-v4.jar im my Eclipse project and included google-play-services.jar. It seems that the ArrayMap class should have been included in android-support-v4.jar ?

According to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/package-summary.html
class ArrayMap is included in the lib?

This is my import list:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ntoapps.sldata.gravmin.R;
```

The question is: where to find the latest updated version of android-support-v4.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
Created a new lib project android-support-v4-util with source code for ArrayMap and needed classes i the src folder. Then this new lib project was included as a separate lib in the project. See Property Android and library projects.
The java files with the classes was found in Android SDK extras.